# Disable woocommerce duplicating short description when product is out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

When the product is out of stock or in backorder i get two short description

[Product out of stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpRs.png)

When product is in stock it is normal

[Product in stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFa6T.png)